# How to identify words with the same meaning in order to reduce number of tags/categories/classes in a dataset

Tags: nlp, dataset, spacy

So here is an example of a column in my data-set:

```
"industries": ["Gaming", "fitness and wellness"]
```

The `industries` column has hundreds of different tags, some of which can have the same meaning, for example, some rows have: `"Gaming"` and some have `"video games"` and others `"Games & consoles"`.

I'd like to "lemmatize" these tags so I could query the data and not worry about minute differences in the presentation (if they are basically the same).

What is the standard solution in this case?

Comment: How are you defining "basically the same" and "minute differences" ? If you can quantify this, or enforce mutual exclusivity between groups of industries, I think that would make this problem tractable.

The issue now is that, for example, if you have "gaming" -- do you want to include a hypothetical "board games" category?

After you answer those questions, the way I would approach this problem is to actually find the embeddings for those spans. You can do this with spacy and the `Doc.vector` attribute.

Comment: I thought about having a threshold of some kind and using it with word2vec's similarity, *distance* (is it the same idea behind Doc.vector?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that there is a "standard" solution, but I can suggest a couple of approaches, ranked by increasing depth of knowledge, or going from the surface form to the meaning.

1. String matching
2. Lemmatisation/stemming
3. Word embedding vector distance

**String matching** is based on the calculating the difference between strings, as a measure of how many characters they share or how many editing steps it takes to transform one into the other. Levenshtein distance is one of the most common ones. However, depending on the size of your data, it might be a bit inefficient to use. [This is a really cool approach to find most similar strings in a large data set](https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html).

However, it might not be the most suitable one for your particular data set, as your similarities seem more semantic and less bound to the surface form of the words.

**Lemmatisation/stemming** goes beyond the surface by analysing the words apart based on their morphology. In your example, *gaming* and *games* both have the same stem *game*, so you could base your similarity measure on matching stems. This can be better than pure string matching as you can see that *go" and *went* are related

**Word embeddings** go beyond the surface form by encoding meaning as the context in which words appear and as such, might find a semantic similarity between *health* and *fitness", that is not apparent from the surface at all! The similarity is measured as the cosine distance/similarity between two word vectors, which is basically the angle between the two vectors.

It seems to me that the third approach might be most suitable for your data.

Comment: See my comment for @Federico Andreoli

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you try .similarity() in spacy and if so, what is it? Or do you get values that don't make sense? You should be able to run it on tokens (i.e. words). If you are using one of their small models, some words might not have a vector associated with them (or rather a 0-vector) because the small models only contain context tensors. So maybe try another model.

(Sorry, don't have enough rep to comment on @Federico Andreoli answer. But his suggestion to use difflib is not using wordvector as far as I understand but simple string similarity.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough NLU question! Basically 'what are synonyms or near synonyms of each other, even if there's not exact string overlap?'.

**1. Use GLoVE word embeddings to judge synonymous words**

It might be interesting to use spaCy's pre-trained GLoVE model (en_vectors_web_lg) for word embeddings, to get the pairwise distances between tokens, and use that as a metric for judging 'closeness'.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_vectors_web_lg')

doc1 = nlp('board games')
doc2 = nlp('Games & Recreation')
doc3 = nlp('video games')

for doc in [doc1, doc2, doc3]:
    for comp in [doc1, doc2, doc3]:
        if doc != comp:
            print(f'{doc} | {comp} | similarity: {round(doc.similarity(comp), 4)}')

board games | Games & Recreation | similarity: 0.6958
board games | video games | similarity: 0.7732
Games & Recreation | board games | similarity: 0.6958
Games & Recreation | video games | similarity: 0.675
video games | board games | similarity: 0.7732
video games | Games & Recreation | similarity: 0.675
```

([GLoVE is cool](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) - really nice mathematical intuition for word embeddings.)

PROS: GLoVE is robust, spaCy has it built in, vector space comparisons are easy in spaCy

CONS: It doesn't handle out of vocabulary words well, spaCy's just taking the average of all the token vectors here (so it's sensitive to document length)

**2. Try using different distance metrics/fuzzy string matching**

You might also look at different kinds of distance metrics -- cosine distance isn't the only one.

[FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is a good implementation of Levenshtein distance for fuzzy string matching (no vectors required).
[This library](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity) implements a whole slew of string-matching algorithms.

PROS: Using a preconfigured library saves you some coding, other distance metrics might help you find new correlations, don't need to train a vector model

CONS: More dependencies, some kinds of distance aren't appropriate and will miss synonymous words without literal string overlap

**3. Use WordNet to get synonym sets**

You could also get a sort of dictionary of synonym sets ('synsets') from WordNet, which was put together by linguists as a kind of semantic knowledge graph.

The nice thing about this is it gets you some *textual entailment* -- that is, given sentence A, would a reader think sentence B is most likely true?

Because it was handmade by linguists and grad students, WordNet isn't as dependent on string overlap and can give you nice semantic enrichment. It also provides things like hyponyms/meroynms and hypernyms/holonyms -- so you could, e.g., say 'video game' is a subtype of 'game', which is a subset of 'recreation' -- just based off of WordNet.

You can access WordNet in python through the [textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) library.

```
from textblob import Word
from textblob.wordnet import NOUN

game = Word('game').get_synsets(pos=NOUN)
for synset in game:
    print(synset.definition())

a contest with rules to determine a winner
a single play of a sport or other contest
an amusement or pastime
animal hunted for food or sport
(tennis) a division of play during which one player serves
(games) the score at a particular point or the score needed to win
the flesh of wild animals that is used for food
a secret scheme to do something (especially something underhand or illegal)
the game equipment needed in order to play a particular game
your occupation or line of work
frivolous or trifling behavior

print(game[0].hyponyms())

[Synset('athletic_game.n.01'),
 Synset('bowling.n.01'),
 Synset('card_game.n.01'),
 Synset('child's_game.n.01'),
 Synset('curling.n.01'),
 Synset('game_of_chance.n.01'),
 Synset('pall-mall.n.01'),
 Synset('parlor_game.n.01'),
 Synset('table_game.n.01'),
 Synset('zero-sum_game.n.01')]
```

Even cooler, you can get the similarity *based on these semantic features* between any words you like.

```
print((Word('card_game').synsets[0]).shortest_path_distance(Word('video_game').synsets[0]))

5
```

PROS: Lets you use semantic information like textual entailment to get at your objective, which is hard to get in other ways

CONS: WordNet is limited to what is in WordNet, so again out-of-vocabulary words may be a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest to use the word2vector approcah or the lemmatisation approach:

- With the first one you can compute vectors starting from words, and so you have a **projection into a vectorial space**. With this projection you can compute the similarity between words (with cosine similarity as @Shnipp sad) and then put a **threshold**, above which you say that two words belong do different arguments.
- Using lemmatisation you can compare bare words/lemma using `SequenceMatcher`. In this case you condition of equality could be based on the presence of very similar lemmas (similarity above 95%).

It's us to you to choose the best for your purpouse. If you want something *solid and structured* use **word2vec**. Othervise if you something *simple and fast* to implement use the **lemmatisation approcah**.

Comment: I've tried using word similarity in spacy (`.similarity()`) but it only seemed to work in a sentance, and not if I give it a single word. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: you can use the SequenceMatcher for single words, it's in the package difflib